# PHP - Prevent F12 submit hacking

Tags: php, mysql, forms, security, submit

Im developing a PHP webapp which have user profiles to create & modify & delete (you know)

When I modify I profile I send the $userID to the PHP page and then I load all the user data. That $userID is store into a hidden input because I need it to launch the UPDATE query after submit.

I have noticed that user can press F12 and change that userID to another one and could modify (or delete) other user profile.

Sorry if is a stupid question, I suppose that this is a common problem in forms submitting, but I don't know how you face it (what is the most secure strategy in this case).

Please help :-)

Comment: use a session variable ie `$_SESSION['userID']` instead of a hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expose a sensitive ID/data.
there is no "security" practice doing that.

you should use a session variable, as @cmrrissey  suggestion

`@session_start(); #at before any outputscript
$_SESSION['userID'] = $senstiveId;`

Also, You should not rely on the frontend validations.
you **must** re-check/validate on your server, what is your end user  sending to you.

Comment: Thanks @Cmorrisey and Quijote, I will do this way.

Quijote when you say its not a gool idea expose ID data, Im using a MVC framework which displays URL like www/users/edit/14 to edit user with ID = 14.  

I have seen it in other well known applications like Moodle, e.g . .../user/edit.php?id=3

Is this a bad practice?

Comment: no its not, its ok querystring the id you want to get for a faster abstraction,  but its different when the end user can manipulate the data, a thing I do is think there will always be a malicious user around, the point is to keep sensitive data on server $_SESSION and check if the posted data belongs to the logged user. with this in mind, you will reach two principles of the information: confidentiality and integrity. if the user change its own that is his problem.